# Clarification on for-loops

Tags: java, arrays, object, logic

Would anyone mind clarifying how exactly i can get a for-loop to increment to the next object in my block of code ive put up? I understand the outside is incrementing by one, however, id like this code to increment by one within the for loop as each element in this case represents a single object. Advice would be much appreciated!!

```
   // create object
    AccountWithInterface accountTemplate = new AccountWithInterface(name, balance, id, rate);

    // declare array of 3 objects
    AccountWithInterface[] accountArray = new AccountWithInterface[3];


    // create each accountArray object
    for(int i = 0; i < accountArray.length; i++) {
        // copy each element (object) from accountTemplate
        accountArray[i] = (AccountWithInterface)accountTemplate.clone();
        // set balance for first object
        accountArray[i].setBalance(85900.32);
        // increment to next object/set object
        accountArray[i].setBalance(3250.99);
        System.out.println(accountArray[i].toString());
    }


           // My output currently keeps printing:
    ID:                            1122
    Created:                   04/13/14
    Owner:                          Bob
    Annual Rate:                   4.50%
    Balance:                   3,250.99

    ID:                            1122
    Created:                   04/13/14
    Owner:                          Bob
    Annual Rate:                   4.50%
    Balance:                   3,250.99

    ID:                            1122
    Created:                   04/13/14
    Owner:                          Bob
    Annual Rate:                   4.50%
    Balance:                   3,250.99
```

Comment: Actually clarification on how one would go about incrementing to the next object is what i think im really not understanding here.

Comment: `accountArray` has null values in it.

Comment: What do you mean by "increment to the next object"...? You are incrementing `i` and thus by accessing array index `[i]` inside the loop you are moving through the array. `i` is 0, then 1, then 2. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Well...sorta. Overall, my goal is to keep each object separate and change all 3 objects balance and then print out each objects balance using my toString method.

Comment: Considering that each object is a clone of the account template, *and* you're doing the same thing to each one, it's not at all surprising that they all look alike.  :P  If you want to do something different to each one, then doing it in a loop kinda defeats the purpose -- unless you have an array of balances and do something like `accountArray[i].setBalance(balances[i]);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really hard to tell what you're asking but taking a guess... if you want to set specific object's balances, just do it outside the loop:

```
// create each accountArray object
for(int i = 0; i < accountArray.length; i++) {
    // copy each element (object) from accountTemplate
    accountArray[i] = (AccountWithInterface)accountTemplate.clone();
}

// set balance for first object
accountArray[0].setBalance(85900.32);
// set balance for second object
accountArray[1].setBalance(3250.99);

for(int i = 0; i < accountArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(accountArray[i].toString());
}
```

Another option is:

```
// create each accountArray object
for(int i = 0; i < accountArray.length; i++) {
    // copy each element (object) from accountTemplate
    accountArray[i] = (AccountWithInterface)accountTemplate.clone();
    if (i == 0)
        accountArray[i].setBalance(85900.32);
    else if (i == 1)
        accountArray[i].setBalance(3250.99);
    System.out.println(accountArray[i].toString());
}
```

Or even something like this:

```
double[] balances = new double[] {85900.32, 3250.99};

// create each accountArray object
for(int i = 0; i < accountArray.length; i++) {
    // copy each element (object) from accountTemplate
    accountArray[i] = (AccountWithInterface)accountTemplate.clone();
    if (i < balances.length)
        accountArray[i].setBalance(balances[i]);
    System.out.println(accountArray[i].toString());
}
```

Whatever is the most appropriate for your situation. You have many options.

Comment: I'm really not a fan of the second option, but I agree with the first and third options.

Comment: @Makoto Agreed; the whole thing is a bit smelly in general. I am wondering why the OP needs to do this in the first place, there may be better higher level ways to organize this code.

Comment: Thanks Jason i was trying to keep everything in one loop. I know i couldve separated the setters for each object but i guess i was trying to stay within the loop. Thanks for the clarification playing around with your code now. Thanks +1

Comment: @user3434674 You're welcome! Hopefully these examples give you some ideas on what is possible. In your original code you were doing exactly the same thing to every object `[i]`, which is why they all turned out the same.

Comment: Also, in your experience Jason which way would you advise in terms of my program using the least memory as well as the most "efficient" way so to speak?

Comment: Excuse any newbie questions..java beginner here :)

Comment: @user3434674 I would advise you to use whichever method leads to the clearest, cleanest, and most maintainable code, and that most accurately represents your intentions. The amount of memory used is insignificant and negligible here, and in general is irrelevant until you find that you are running out of it -- in other words, design well, concentrate on writing *correct* code, *then* optimize if your performance/resource requirements aren't being met, and even then only after identifying where optimizations actually need to be done.

Comment: "Design well, concentrate on writing correct code, then optimize if your performance/resource requirements aren't being met" <--Words of wisdom right there ;)